# CSS selector for element with a specific child :hover'ed

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given this HTML:

```
<ul class="root">
   <li class="a">A</li>
   <li class="b">B</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to write a CSS selector that sets properties on `.root` when the mouse hovers over `.a`?

To be clear, I do NOT mean this:

```css
ul.root li.a:hover { }
```

This would apply properties to the child when it's hovered over.  I want to apply the properties to the root when the child is hovered.

I could fall back on JavaScript, but I'd rather use CSS if it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS alone because, as mentioned in numerous other questions ([such as...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+selector+parent+ancestor)), there's no CSS parent selector. You'll have to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for a clear explanation.  I did a fair bit of searching on this topic before posting, but didn't find anything.  I didn't phrase it quite right, perhaps.